# What type of room divider should I use to convert a dining room into a bed room?

Tags: bedroom

My dining room has 2 openings:
96H x 64W (do not need a door/opening)
96H x 41W (sliding door)

What are my best options to install something which is sturdy (not removable).

None of them should be glass doors as it'd be a bedroom. Noise separation would be good but not a must.

Comment: When I was in university, we used a few panels of ~2.5" XPS foam to make a partition wall so a dining room could be a bedroom. Ugly as hell, but easy, functional, cheap, and actually made a good sound insulator. True story, but I don't recommend doing this unless you're under 21 and can justify it with the fact most of your money goes to tuition and beer.

Answer (score 2):

My personal perference would be to remove the trim and floor under the opening, frame with 2x4's and then drywall.  Paint and re-trim.

The pocket door will take a little more work depending on where the hinges will be.  If the hinges will be on the side where the door slides into the wall, you will need to open the wall and re-frame that section.  If the door handle will go on that side, you can get away with filling the old pocket with a 2x4, but the wall will be stronger if you re-frame where the pocket was.  Remove the trim, order a custom pre-hung door, install door, re-trim the new door.

Answer (score 1):

1. Quick and Dirty - Get double doors with pins that go into the jamb and floor to hold the center closed, and lock them.  Advantage: Undo-able.
2. Permanent:  See diceless's answer.
3. Semi-Permanent: Create a 2x4 stud wall that just fits in the
   existing door.  Nail it to the door jamb.  Cover with drywall, or
   awesome 1970's basement paneling.  Put the dresser in front of the
   door area where the casing is visible, or put the head of the bed so
   that it's framed by the casing.

Answer (score 1):

Diceless and Chris given some solid suggestions so I'll just throw out one more option here by way of this [link](http://www.barndoorshardware.com/#doors). These sliding barn doors are a lot easier to install than a pocket door and add a nice architectural element to the room.

Comment: This answer is close to [being in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/997587). It would be nice to say the name of the product in the post itself instead of just "this link" and "these sliding barn doors".